# Are there any new (or at least working) pseudo-3D icon sets anymore?

Tags: theme, icons

I just need some tips: where can I still find good complete pseudo-3D icon sets for Linux, especially Xfce?

Even when I search for "non-flat icons" on Google, half of the entries say "ultra-flat". Everybody seems in [adoration of flatness](https://icons8.com/articles/why-are-so-many-companies-changing-to-flat-logo-design/). Everything [is flat](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/4fda6p/what_are_some_good_nonflat_icon_themes_for_gnome/d27vv91/?st=j8ftixho&sh=8c29bd83).

I have nothing against flat icons as long as I have a choice, but it seems I don't anymore. In fact flatness seemed so logical and obvious that I was glad to adopt it, but after a while I realized something was missing. I never liked excessive [skeumorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Redstair_GEARcompressor.png) in a music player's GUI, but after a while I think it is preferable as far as icons are concerned. Why? Because an "icon" is a symbol, but not a letter; it should be the image of something; but a too-flat icon looks like the image of an image, like the quote of a quote. Or maybe it's just my mind that wants **Firefox to have a fox-looking animal in its icon, not just a spot of orange, a folder icon to look like a folder and not just a rectangle**.

I think **flat icons serve their purpose only as long as we know the non-flat image that they refer to**. I notice that my mind  needs to know the first anyway in order to use the second, and that it asks for a fraction of a second more to recognize a flat icon for what it is.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I fully agree with you. Concerning UI it looks like we're back in the 1980s. Hell, even AmigaOS in 1985 featured 3D icons!

Comment: Firefox icon is branding by Mozilla and does not really belong to any icon theme set. Not sure what icon theme is considered pseudo-3D... Can OP name any pseudo-3D icon theme set that OP were using previously?

Comment: @clearkimura - `Firefox icon is branding by Mozilla and does not really belong to any icon theme set`. The first is the one branded by Mozilla. The other two are part of icon sets that in my view should keep in mind the original. I was trying to illustrate a ***trend*** where icons go too far from what they need to represent. - I was looking for *recent* non-flat sets.

Comment: It's ancient at this point, but I'm still partial to Echo.

Comment: @clearkimura - sorry that I have missed a part of your comment: 3D icons were very common in the past. Example, the Oxigen set for KDE, which is old enough now, though usable. There was also the [Cristal](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1002592/) set, that I was not able to find. Faenza is flatter, but still resisting the full-flatness, and is now continued as Delft. For that, see my answer, where I also mention an old super-3D set,  FS Icons Ubuntu, which can still be downloaded.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - where can you download it now? FS Icons Ubuntu is old too but can be found.

Comment: If your distro doesn't already have a package for it then you can build it [from source](https://pagure.io/echo-project), although I couldn't tell you how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is of course **Faenza** and related sets that are not really recent.

One that is recent and based on Faenza is [**Delft**](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1199881/). It looks very much like Faenza.

[image]

There is also a rather recent [Oxygen Remixed Icons](https://store.kde.org/p/1160037/)

[image]
**Evolvere**, **Breeze**, **Flat Remix** and **Vivacious** icons seem a good compromise between having a modern icon set and having clear and meaningful icons; without contradicting completely the flattening trend, they are clear, crisp, visible.

An older set - but one that is poignantly non-flat: [**FS Icons Ubuntu**](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1012533/) - which links to [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/245dbpib9ajotvv/fs-icons-ubuntu-0.6-alpha4.zip). Also [here](https://launchpad.net/fs-icons-ubuntu).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's [some free desktop icons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Desktop_icons). They're for GNOME and not for Xfce, but hope it's a beginning.

Comment: Thanks. But shouldn't these confirm the initial idea that there are no non-flat icon themes created in the last few years?..